# Failed to Compile: 'movies' is not defined (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined

I'm getting this error message in a react app when I'm attempting to search for a movie and return a response of an array of movies.

```
src/App.js
  Line 42:9:   'movies' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 42:19:  'movies' is not defined  no-undef
```

Here is src/App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import unirest from 'unirest';
import Movie from './movie';
import Search from './search';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: []
  }

 sendRequest = (title) => {

   const req = unirest("GET", "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/");

   req.query({
     "page": "1",
     "r": "json",
     "s": title
   });

   req.headers({
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'my_api_key'
   });


   req.end((res) => {
     if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
     const movies = res.body.Search;
     this.setState({movies});

     console.log(res.body);
   });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
       {
        movies && movies.length ? this.state.movies.map((movie) => {
          return <Movie {...movie}/>
        })
        : null
        }
         <Search handleSendRequest={this.sendRequest}/>
       </header>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

I'm not sure why it's saying 'movies' is undefined, I've set it as part of state in the beginning of the class itself. It seems like the req.end function is not accessing the state object for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Either you have to spread the state in render or use `this.state.movies`.

**Using Destructuring**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import unirest from 'unirest';
import Movie from './movie';
import Search from './search';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: []
  }

 sendRequest = (title) => {

   const req = unirest("GET", "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/");

   req.query({
     "page": "1",
     "r": "json",
     "s": title
   });

   req.headers({
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'my_api_key'
   });


   req.end((res) => {
     if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
     const movies = res.body.Search;
     this.setState({movies});

     console.log(res.body);
   });
 }

 render() {
   const {movies} = this.state; // Use Destructuring
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
       {
        movies && movies.length ? this.state.movies.map((movie) => {
          return <Movie {...movie}/>
        })
        : null
        }
         <Search handleSendRequest={this.sendRequest}/>
       </header>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Or access state

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import unirest from 'unirest';
import Movie from './movie';
import Search from './search';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: []
  }

 sendRequest = (title) => {

   const req = unirest("GET", "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/");

   req.query({
     "page": "1",
     "r": "json",
     "s": title
   });

   req.headers({
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'my_api_key'
   });


   req.end((res) => {
     if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
     const movies = res.body.Search;
     this.setState({movies});

     console.log(res.body);
   });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
       { // Use this.state to access movies. 
        this.state.movies && this.state.movies.length ? this.state.movies.map((movie) => {
          return <Movie {...movie}/>
        })
        : null
        }
         <Search handleSendRequest={this.sendRequest}/>
       </header>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

EDIT: Fixing `res.body` undefined.

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import unirest from 'unirest';
import Movie from './movie';
import Search from './search';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    movies: []
  }

 sendRequest = (title) => {

   const req = unirest("GET", "https://movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com/");

   req.query({
     "page": "1",
     "r": "json",
     "s": title
   });

   req.headers({
    'x-rapidapi-host': 'movie-database-imdb-alternative.p.rapidapi.com',
    'x-rapidapi-key': 'my_api_key'
   });


   req.end((res) => {
     if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
     if(res && res.body && res.body.Search) {
       const movies = res.body.Search;
       this.setState({movies});
     }
     console.log(res.body);
   });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <header className="App-header">
       {
        this.state.movies && this.state.movies.length ? this.state.movies.map((movie) => {
          return <Movie {...movie}/>
        })
        : null
        }
         <Search handleSendRequest={this.sendRequest}/>
       </header>
     </div>
   );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This works, in as much as it changes the error to the following:
"TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Search')"

  27 | 
  28 | req.end((res) => {
  29 |   if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error);
> 30 |   const movies = res.body.Search;
     | ^  31 |   this.setState({movies});
  32 | 
  33 |   console.log(res.body);

Comment: Can you put a `console.log(res.body.Search)` before you set the state? or a debugger? Maybe you need to debug the response that you're getting.

Comment: You have `res.body` as undefined probably. Need to check if you are getting a response before setting the state.

Comment: I changed the existing console.log to console.log(res.body.Search) and that didn't change anything. I still get the same error.

Comment: You need to check what you are getting in that console.log, It is possible that your res.body is undefined.

Comment: I have added the 3rd example in the answer. Try that, Also check if it is returning the `Search` attribute in the body.